# Dynamically disable angular mat radio checkbox, based on radio button value

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, radio-button, conditional-statements

I have a use case where , I need to disable 2 check boxes from list of check boxes depending on the radio button value chose. From the way I have implemented at the moment all the check boxes are being disabled.

```
<mat-radio-group  (change)="filterDashBoardActivated($event)">
     <mat-radio-button [value] ="0"><b>Dash Board Filter</b> </mat-radio-button>
     <mat-radio-button [value] ="1"><b>Download Excel Sheet</b></mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

The code above showcases how I have implemented the 2 radio buttons.

```
 filterDashBoardActivated(radioButton: MatRadioChange) {
    if(radioButton.value === 1){
        this.isExcelDownloadEnabled = true;
    }else{
        this.isExcelDownloadEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

The above function is executed when the radio button value is change. If the value I have gotten is 1 the 2 check boxes from the check box should be disabled. I have declared a variable named *isExcelDownloadEnabled* and I have passed it as the condition for the check boxes that I need to be disabled when it is true as below,

```
 <mat-checkbox name="all"><b>Select</b></mat-checkbox>
 <mat-checkbox name="all"><b>City</b></mat-checkbox>
 <mat-checkbox name="all"[disabled]="isExcelDownloadEnabled"><b>All</b>
 </mat-checkbox>
 <mat-checkbox name="all" [disabled]="isExcelDownloadEnabled">Town      
 </mat-checkbox>
```

But at the moment when *isExcelDownloadEnabled* is true all the check boxes gets disabled and I have not added the *isExcelDownloadEnabled* condition to other check boxes.

Is there something wrong in the approach I have taken? Why are all the check boxes getting disabled even though the condition I have used is only implemented in one checkbox?

Comment: Can you add a working demo link of your use case?

Comment: show other checkbox code too! and in your template check boxes are inside *ngFor or not ? @GeorgeSilva

Comment: @GaurangDhorda I have added the the rest of the check boxes as well, no they are not inside *ngFor

Comment: @GeorgeSilva `[disabled]="!isExcelDownloadEnabled"` try like this

Comment: That actually disables all the check boxes when the form is loaded, and has the opposite effects while changing the 2 radio buttons @GaurangDhorda

Comment: Do you use reactive form too @GeorgeSilva

Comment: @GaurangDhorda No I am not using reactive forms

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232451/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-george-silva).